# SpringMVC - How to clear cache only when user log out

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, caching

Currently I have the following filter that clear the cache for each request:

```
public class CacheControlFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CacheControlFilter.class);


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;


        resp.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        resp.setHeader("Last-Modified", new Date().toString());
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        resp.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
        resp.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Please find logout method below:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    request.getSession().invalidate();


    return Constants.LOGOUT;

    }
```

Is there a way to clear cache only when user log out instead of each request? I want to store my static files(css files,js files) in cache and clear it only when user log out

Any advice is most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Which cache? The `CacheControlFilter` doesn't clear anything.

Comment: You can specify the filter only run when the path is /logout in the web.xml

Comment: The response header cache is cleared

Comment: ohh how can I specify the filter to run only /logout?

Comment: Thanks Eric works smoothly  cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please configure your filter into web.xml for /logout url only like:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CacheControlFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class><YOUR_PACKAGE>.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CacheControlFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And if not using web.xml see this link:

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/how-to-register-a-servlet-filter-in-spring-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

you can register the cache filter via the initializer class.

```
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[]{new CacheControlFilter()};
}
```

Good luck